# Unable to use Angular Core library when using nx

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-angular

I am trying to migrate my app to nx app. I am almost at the end, but the problm is that whenever I add Angular module or Angular component to that library, I get following error:
`ESLint: Buildable libraries cannot import or export from non-buildable libraries(@nx/enforce-module-boundaries)`

Importing another library works fine.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; // DOES NOT WORK
import { testFunction } from '@another-library/test2'; // WORKS

@Component({
  selector: 'web-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {
  testFunctionEx(): void {
    testFunction();
  }
}
```

Apart from disabling boundaries I haven't found a solution...